# Determining whether an operator is Hermitian

Tags: operator-algebras

> The operator $F$ is defined by $F\psi(x)=\psi(x+a)+\psi(x-a) $, where $a$ is a nonzero constant. Determine whether or not $F$ is a Hermitian operator.

If the condition for $F$ to be Hermitian is $(\psi|F\psi)=(F\psi|\psi)$,

then $(\psi|F\psi)=\int\psi^*(\psi(x+a)+\psi(x-a))dx$

and $(F\psi|\psi)=\int(\psi^*(x+a)+\psi^*(x-a))\psi dx$

how can I show equality?

Comment: It's $\left <F\psi|\phi \right> = \left <\psi|F\phi \right>$

Comment: @Kaster That's certainly the more straightforward definition, but you can obtain this from $\langle F\psi | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | F\psi \rangle$ by polarization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using linearity of the inner product and change of variables in the integral. 
$$
(F\psi \mid \phi) = (\psi_a + \psi_{-a}\mid\phi) = (\psi_a\mid\phi) +(\psi_{-a}\mid\phi)
$$
Where the subscript in $\psi_a$ means translation by $a$. Change of variables ($x'=x+a$) in the integral implies $(\psi_a\mid\phi) = (\psi\mid\phi_{-a})$ and vice versa. 
$$
 (\psi_a\mid\phi) +(\psi_{-a}\mid\phi) = (\psi\mid\phi_{-a})+(\psi\mid\phi_{a}) = (\psi\mid F\phi)
$$